# entity framework navigation property to table in different db

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 tables in different db

```
db1..Towns
    id
    Nazv

db2..MathchedTown
    id
    t_id
    d_name
```

They are joined by по Towns.id = MathchedTown.t_id
This EF classes:

```
[Table("Towns")]
    public class Town
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Nazv { get; set; }
    }
[Table("MathchedTown")]
    public class mTown
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string t_id{ get; set; } 

        [Required]
        public string d_name{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("t_id")]
        public virtual Town town { get; set; }

    }
```

when i try to get item.town.nazv i get error:
Invalid object name 'dbo.Towns'.
If i change [Table("Towns")] to [Table("db1.dbo.Towns")], then appear almost the same error: Invalid object name 'dbo.db1.dbo.Towns'.

That all errors are SqlExceptions

How i can talk EF4 don't substite the "dbo." prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework does not support multiple databases in a single context. But it supports multiple schemas in a single database. If you do not specify the schema it will assume `dbo`.

```
[Table("Towns", "MySchema")]
public class Town
```

You can specify the schema as above.

If you want to use a table in a different database you can create a view to that table in your database. But it will be read only.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately EF4 does not support navigation property that is in other db.
You have two choices.

One, create a stored procedure and import it as a function in edm. And genetate complex type for the return result.

Two, create two entity models for each database. And run a query for a database then run the other query to the other database with where clause from the first query result.